# Do I need to install BizTalk server on client to just run the policies?

Tags: dll, deployment, biztalk, biztalk-rule-engine

I have a .Net application which is being deployed at the client (Database and the application). Whenever client requests a new feature I have to deploy a new build on the application URL. Currently I am looking into BizTalk server's Business Rule Engine. I have created one policy with set of rules. I want to know how will it work with my current application structure.

Do I need to install any service on client side to make that policy run? Or simply importing the "RuleEngine" reference in my code and then deploying it will work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use BizTalk Rule Engine independently from BizTalk Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178320/is-it-possible-to-use-biztalk-rule-engine-independently-from-biztalk-server)

Answer (score 3):

Few points to cover, #3 likely being you deciding factor.

1. The Business Rule Engine ships only with BizTalk Server so you must install the BizTalk Server *Product* on any computer where you need to run the Business Rules Engine.
2. You do not need to install the BizTalk Server runtime.
3. To run the Business Rules Engine, **you must have a valid BizTalk Server license**.  The BRE is not available separately.
4. The BRE runs entirely in-process.  So, the answer to question 2 is yes, but you will need to load the policies manually if you are not using the Rules Engine Update Service.

Comment: So if I install BizTalk server on my machine and create a policy (using rule composer) and then execute that policy in my code by including _RuleEngine.dll_ and deploy the build. Is there any way I can simply deploy the policy along with the code? So that client doesn't have to do anything. (I am thinking of an xml file with the policy included in the project and deployed along)

Comment: Well...no, not legitimately.  They would still need to install the BizTalk Server product since that is how the BRE is distributed.  This is regardless of the technical ability to host the Engine and load the policies in code.

Answer (score 0):

The BRE framework is a separate framework, you can installed it without install the BizTalk in your client machine.

But you have to check if you need the BizTalk license to run BRE component in the client machine.

Comment: As far as I know it can only be used with in BizTalk server. The maximum you could do is only install BRE components while installing BizTalk servre. But, I don't know if it exists merely as a standalone framework. If it's possible to use it as separate framework that would be great!

Comment: @talaa123 I believe both johns-305 and my answer pointed out the biggest problem of this approach, it is not about technically doable or not, it is about licensing. If you deploy rule engine.dll to 10 client machines. You have to purchase biztalk license for these 10 machines even you don't deploy biztalk runtime on it.